# error input auto_increment program and undetected column

Tags: mysql

I create table in `MySQL` code

```
CREATE TABLE beli(
id_beli INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
kd_barang VARCHAR( 5 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
nama_barang VARCHAR( 20 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
jumlah INT( 11 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( id_beli )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Insert data in the table

```
INSERT INTO beli (kd_barang, nama_barang, jumlah)
VALUES("K001","Kayu",30);
```

But, unfortunately error in my program and it written like this

> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'ks_barang' in 'field list'

Comment: That error can't come from the code you posted. But the real code has a typo: `ks_barang` should be `kd_barang`.

Comment: after i recreate this table the program not error, mybe i write the wrong code

Comment: yes that's what Barmar said, it's correct. You can delete this question, it is not useful to anyone.